# No file or directory found

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I downloaded Code blocks 17.12 and then followed:- new project:-console application:-c++

Now when I write the following code it does not run:-

```
#include<iostream>

void main()
{
    std:: cout<<"Hello";
}
```

It shows no file or directory found.
The weird thing is that when I run a C program on code blocks no such error comes.

I reinstalled code blocks a couple of times but the problem still remains same.

I also tried going on tool chain executables and then auto detect but it didn't help either.

Ps: When I created C++ project the usual "Hello World" program file that comes didn't show. All that came was this :
[Code Blocks IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vL7V.png)

[When I clicked on resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkcnv.png)

Comment: I presume you installed Code:Blocks with the TDM-MinGW gcc compiler? The IDE looks fine in your screenshot, the project doesn't look setup. Did you follow the wizard and setup the "Console Application" choosing C++ and making sure you didn't mess with the default compiler `GNU gcc` listed in the project? Further, where did `void main()` come from? That is a non-conforming invocation of `main()`. Conforming invocations are `int main (void)` or `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` (which you will see equivalently as `int main (int argc, char **argv)`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin in `C++` you do not need to declare parameter list as `(void)` an empty parameter list already means no parameters.

Comment: You are right. That's a bit of C bleedover.

Comment: Also Soham, you will have to make sure your CodeBlocks setting are correct (which is what you must do with any IDE). I would suggest, you set your PATH to contain `C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin` (start->Rt. click computer -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables) then (in top box, Add (or Edit) `Path` and include the path to the `...\MinGW\bin` directory. Then you can simply open a Command Prompt and change to your source directory and `g++ -Wall -Wextra -O3 -o yourprog.exe yourprog.cpp`  to compile it. Then you can tell the IDE what to do.

Comment: Ah, then I suspect the CodeBlocks IDE still has some settings looking for an install on `C:`. Here is a decent write up on what to check [How To Install and Get Started](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/CodeBlocks_HowTo.html) in addition to [Installing a supported compiler](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Installing_a_supported_compiler)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Code Blocks be sure that you downloaded version with needed pack, every C++ code works fine with standard Compiler GNU Compiler C/С++ (if i don't miss something with name of it).

On your screen you don't choose any compiler as Code Blocks sad and you don't choose your file with main function.

Code should be like this:

```
#include <iostream> // Space here.

using namespace std; // No need to write std every cout.

int main() // Int here.
{
  cout<<"Hello";

  return 0; // Because of int return type. In some cases it needs for right ending of program.
}
```